# Scroll bar style for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

What is the equivalent for:

```
.feed::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 8px;

}

.feed::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 3px;

}
```

in **IE**? I found this:
[-ms-overflow-style property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx) but got lost :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a custom scroll bars in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698207/how-to-make-a-custom-scroll-bars-in-ie)

Comment: I saw explanations about the colors only in that question..Do you have info about the width?

Comment: My limited research (just now) indicates that there is (currently) no way to affect the dimensions of scrollbars in IE. Cross-browser compatibility is a headache; be kind to yourself and accept that users with different browsers **will** have different experiences, and that's their choice.

Comment: I ended up styling only the colors for every other browser than Chrome.