# Bootstrap 4 Custom Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently working on a project which develops a website front-end using Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4. All we need to do is create a custom scroll bar, which works on any modern browser. (Not like CSS `::-webkit-scrollbar` which does not work in IE and FF) This scroll bar should be exactly like the image below and it must be appear, when a user hover the main element. Is this possible? How do we do this? Any of advice is much appreciated.
[Sample Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPMKe.jpg)

Comment: I used `jquery-slimscroll` before. It does what you want. I don't know if there is angular version of it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-slimscroll

Comment: @DavidLiang Thank you very much for help. I have just inspected some elemts of this sample site. it is <div class="nano-slider">

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698672/7680307

Comment: @DayOne Thank you..!!! It is really worth. I think I got what I want. It was nano-scrollbar. https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. It is called Nano Scroller. [Nano Scroller](https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

It also fade-in when user hover the mouse over the parent element. Thank you everyone who helped me by commenting.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable to the community, and library recommendations are off topic. See [answer] and the [help].